# ElasticMapReduce: number of mappers/reducers per EC2 type

Tags: hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

I am wondering whether the number of mappers and reducers would be different based on the instance type of EC2 servers you choose? I found Large instance is using 3 mappers and 1 reducers. Would that be the same for every other type (for example, xLarge instance)? I know I can override it thru bootstraping but just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't same for every instance types.
Amazon has a concept of Hadoop Default Configurations, which is controlled by AMI versions, latest one is AMI-2.3 .
These configurations define the default value for a number of hadoop configurations, for example for a m1.xlarge, following configurations are set by default of you use AMI-2.3

```
Parameter   Value
HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_HEAPSIZE  6912
HADOOP_NAMENODE_HEAPSIZE    2304
HADOOP_TASKTRACKER_HEAPSIZE 384
HADOOP_DATANODE_HEAPSIZE    384
mapred.child.java.opts  -Xmx768m
mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum    8
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum 3
```

For more see the following:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/HadoopMemoryDefault_AMI2.3.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-config.html

Comment: Indeed I ran xLarge instance on EMR and found 8 mappers and 3 reducers per instance.

Comment: for the default number of mappers / reducers by ami type, see this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/TaskConfiguration.html